# Is it possible to transfer koi to a new phone?

Tags: zen-koi

Is it possible to transfer my dragons and other koi to my new phone? I know that you can connect to Facebook and Google Play Games. Will they automatically transfer or do I have to start over?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Zen Koi FAQ](https://web.facebook.com/notes/zen-koi/frequently-asked-questions/1686356868311368/?_rdr), each device has it's own separate game/progress:

> #### Can I play on different devices and have the progress of each game linked?
>
> Zen Koi do not have syncing feature, even if you have Facebook connect ON, it only helps save the progress. When you play on another device, your progress will not be linked even if you have Facebook connect ON.

---

You might be able to contact the developer's support about how to permanently transfer your progress across to a different device. I cannot guarantee they will be able to help you do this however.

You can do this in-game by clicking on the 'Support' icon in 'Help:

[image: Help Page]

Or by emailing the support team: support@landsharkgames.com

#### References

- [Zen Koi Support Page](http://zenkoigame.com/support/)